# How to create connection for two different data sources in singleton class in java

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, singleton

I have one class name DBManager.java, this class implements a singleton design pattern and this is used for all DB operations. 
This works perfectly when I have to connect with 1 data source, Now in my project, I have to connect with 2 different data sources, Now when I use this class, this behaves differently. because it always returns 1 data source connection.

Now how can I manage this, in a better way? One approach is I would create another DBManager2.java class and use this class for the 2nd data source, but I don't think so it's a good way.

Any recommendation.

Comment: If you ask me, I will easily go with 2 different datasources which separate my concerns. You can easily implement from an Interface and store these singletons created in a Map. Something like
Map<String, InterfaceOfDb1ANdDb2>

Comment: Did `DBManager` really need to be a singleton to begin with?  Is `DBManager` injected into a DAO through a constructor or setter?  Or is a DAO self aware and calls `DBManager.getInstance().getConnection()`?  Post some code so we can suggest some refactoring steps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Map<Key, DataSource>` to store datasources by some key. And then use some key object to get corresponding datasoucre (database URL, database user or some identifier)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an `enum` with the different databases as different enum constants:

```
public enum Databases{ 
    DB1,
    DB2 
}
```

And then use that in your `DBManager.getConnection()` method:

```
public final class DBManager{
    // singleton stuff

    public Connection getConnection(Databases d){
        switch(d){
            case DB1:
                // return connection to db1
            case DB2:
                // return connection to db2
        }
    }
}
```

By using a switch you can just create a new branch for every database.

Another way would be to store all the information needed for the connection in the enum itself. Although that way there'd b many security flaws, because you just hardcode database credentials into your code (which should not be done).